# Table with axis

Tags: tables

I need to make this table with an axis.
can someone help me?

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please consider to add a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to see what you've done so far.

Comment: You might look up matrix from the tikz package.

Comment: yes but i don't know to put the axis in a precise manner as in figure... sorry, I'm a beginner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with this.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={minimum width=3.2cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center, draw, anchor=center},
    column 1/.style={nodes={minimum width=1cm}}]
    {
    $X_a$ & & |[fill=gray!50]| $\Omega_1=\mu\pm\varepsilon$ &
    |[fill=gray!50]| $\Omega_1=\mu\pm\varepsilon-\pi/2$ & \\
    $X_b$ & & & & |[fill=gray!50]| $\Omega_1=\mu$ \\
    $X_c$ & |[fill=gray!50]| $\Omega_1=\mu$& & &\\};
\draw[->] (A.south-|A-3-1.east)--([xshift=2mm]A.south east) coordinate (aux);
\node[below= 1mm of {A.south-|A-3-2.east}] {$-\Lambda_0/\Lambda_1$};
\node[below= 1mm of {A.south-|A-3-3.east}] {$0$};
\node[below= 1mm of {A.south-|A-3-4.east}] {$\Lambda_0/\Lambda_1$};
\node[below= 1mm of {A.south-|aux}] {$U/V$};
\node[fill=white, minimum width=3.2cm,minimum height=1cm,draw, anchor=west] at ([xshift=5mm]A-1-2.north west) {Case $L=0$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Ignasi.... I compile your code but the third column are smaller than others.
Also if I want change the linestyle (i.e dashed line or double line or bold line) of the table, how can I do?
Thank youu

Comment: @MatteoBuscicchio `matrix` is not like `tabular`, in `matrix` every node has its own size (try suppressing `minimum width` in `nodes` declaration) and if your `minimum size` is shorter than needed size for first node in third column all other nodes look smaller because the default size is smaller. If you want to change line style, just add it in `nodes` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Ignasi.... I compile your code but the third column are smaller than others. Also if I want change the linestyle (i.e dashed line or double line or bold line) of the table, how can I do? Thank youu[image]